# stretch images for Android devices

Tags: android, resolution

I have been programming an application for Android. I want to target it for more devices(tablets, smartphones). I tried to find some info at http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html but it does not work correctly.

I want to automatically stretch images on different devices, not only in my testing device. I draw images for the mobile full screen (which has the same resolution as my mobile). But, for example in the tablet it draws incorrectly. I tried to change the size and it gives several folders(lhdpi, small, ...). When I tried to start it again in the tablet, it was bigger but still incorrect (there was a black space on the edges). I have several images in my application, and I want to retain the same size as in the mobile too. Please, help me.

Sorry for my spelling mistakes.

Comment: put inside AndroidManifest.xml
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true"></supports-screens>

Answer (score 0):

you have to maintain aspect ratio at your own . don't put same sized images in all folder (hdli, mdpi, ldpi), if this was the case they think why android provides different foldes ? put images in ratio 0.75 : 1 : 1.5 . it will work . 
additionally read about 9-patch images, this will make your life much easier .

Comment: I haven't same size images in folder. But when I started a app with a image on the tablet, it created the app with a image from drawable-xlarge. That is correct, but it did not draw the image on full screen, but when I started the app on the mobile, it drawed it on full screen. On the tablet I had a little black space. A want to a image draw on full screen, for example as background.

Comment: looks like you set fixed width/height to your view which is near to mobile device size. do it fill parent i will say

Comment: I set layout as match_parent for width and height. In the layout I have <com.example.screen.ViewImage ... /> - there is a view when I have the image, which I draw.

Comment: I have created a simple web, where I have copied my all code of application. This is the web: http://code.weblahko.sk/?gen=4189